# htaccess 301 with a more complex redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client domain with thousands of pages that are moving to a new domain. The naming convention of the .html has changed, and I know htaccess can handle this somehow.

Here's an example:

old site: http://oldsite.com/west-virginia/new-cumberland-wv-index.html

new site: http://newsite.com/west-virginia/computer-support-new-cumberland-wv-index.html

I also have a few issues where things like newcumberland are renamed to new-cumberland

This is beyond my understanding at the moment. I'd appreciate a little help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may need to do this on a case-by-case basis unless you can find a definitive pattern to these changes. The redirects themselves would look something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1/computer-support-$2.html
```

The first `([^/]+)` matches the state, and the second `([^/]+)` matches the name of the html file. This redirect simply adds a `computer-support-` in front of the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction! Here's the final implementation:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(computer-repair-in-)(.+)-index\.html$ http://newsite.com/$1/computer-support-$3-index.html [QSA,R=301]
```